# Хороший, плохой (?) главное — у кого ружьё

Tags: пунктуация

Цитата из перевода "Армии тьмы" ("Зловещие мертвецы 3"). Всегда интересовало, как она правильно записывается. Я бы, например, поставил длинное тире. Но мне представляется, что неправильное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, так записывается: **Хороший, плохой... Главное — у кого ружьё.**

Вполне логично. Многоточие обозначает незаконченность фразы, подразумевается: какая разница!